# SSIS Flat file column delimiter

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, delimiter

I have a csv file that I process and import into a database. the problem is the delimiter needs to be " but within SSIS is this possible as currently the default options are :-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text box for the Column delimiter can be edited by clicking in it and writing whatever column delimiter you need.

[image: Just type it in the text box.]

Answer (score 0):

you can enter in any delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Just write it by yourself in the text box. Your choice is not limited with the values listed in the drop down list.